# Unable to build/run a program in VB 6.0 in vista

Tags: windows-vista, visual-c++

As I have to work on VC++, I've installed Visual Basic 6.0 on my Windows Vista Home Premium 32-bit, 1 GB RAM. During installation I got many pop-up messages saying 'Not Compatible' and was also not able to install many header files. I ignored all these and was able to complete the set up. I've also installed the latest patch of VB 6.0 But after rebooting, etc., when I write a program and build one, it says something like 'error.exe'. Thank you. O_o

**EDIT:** I need to use VC++ for building MFC Applications. I'm working on Vista, is there any alternative for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Windows Vista does not support Visual Studio 6, unless you are installing a very specific subset of Visual Basic 6.0 **only**.

Your question seems to mix VC++ and VB so I'm not sure what your machine state is in, but I can assure you that Visual C++ 6.0 **will not run** on anything higher than Windows XP.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to use VC++ for building MFC Applications. Is there any alternative for this problem?

Comment: Run a virtual machine with Windows XP, and then install VC++ in there. If you had Windows 7, I'd suggest Virtual XP Mode.